# Cisco 2960L and ISR 4331 throttled WAN speeds

Tags: cisco, switch, router, throughput

I have tried finding a solution to this issue and the closest I have found thus far can be found here. https://www.reddit.com/r/networking/comments/8f2sn0/throughput_limited_by_cisco_2960_switch/
My networking knowledge is limited and I don't quite understand what is being discussed or how to go about testing it yet.

Any help would be appreciated, this is driving me crazy! I will post some config snippets tomorrow when I return to the office.

The Issue:

We have a 72Mb download and 20Mb upload package from the ISP. This connects to a Cisco ISR 4331 on gig 0/0/1 with the 100Mb license installed. When connecting a computer directly to the ISR 4331 on gig 0/0/1 the ISP throughput is achieved consistently on speedtest.net

We have a Cisco 2960L switch with Vlans. JPERF test between two computers connected to two different Vlans gives us 940Mb speeds, so interVlan routing locally is running great.

We have created a routed port on the 2960L on gig0/1 connected to ISR 4331 gig 0/0/0 on their own VLAN. Auto negotiate and no extra configuration on these ports. Same computers connected on the switchports and everything is working as would be expected however when running the speedtest again on speedtest.net on the same computer the throughput is consistently throttled to between 35-50 Mb Download and 3-6Mb upload.

All computers on all Vlans experience this throttling. Download speeds on speedtest can be erratic and sometimes shoot up to 55Mb or 60Mb, upload speeds are consistently in the range of 3-6Mb for all computers on the network.

JPERF between various computers connected to the 2960L show upwards of 900Mb speeds.

What could be the most likely cause of this ?

**EDIT:**

2960L Gig 0/47 is now connected to 4331 using Gig 0/0/0 using a new patch cable

[image]

**EDIT: 2960L Switch Config:**

```
! Last configuration change at 18:54:01 GMT Tue Apr 9 2019
! NVRAM config last updated at 19:10:56 GMT Tue Apr 9 2019 by 
!
version 15.2
no service pad
service timestamps debug datetime msec
service timestamps log datetime msec
service password-encryption
!
hostname DXBSWBHMAINRACK
!
boot-start-marker
boot-end-marker
!
enable secret 5 
!
username secret 5 
no aaa new-model
clock timezone GMT 4 0
ip routing
ip dhcp excluded-address 172.17.2.17
ip dhcp excluded-address 172.17.2.1
ip dhcp excluded-address 172.17.2.33
ip dhcp excluded-address 172.17.0.1
ip dhcp excluded-address 172.17.1.1
ip dhcp excluded-address 172.17.9.1
ip dhcp excluded-address 172.17.2.65
ip dhcp excluded-address 172.17.2.70
ip dhcp excluded-address 172.17.8.1 172.17.8.2
ip dhcp excluded-address 172.17.8.33 172.17.8.34
ip dhcp excluded-address 172.17.8.97 172.17.8.98
ip dhcp excluded-address 172.17.8.66
ip dhcp excluded-address 172.17.8.65
ip dhcp excluded-address 172.17.2.73 172.17.2.74
ip dhcp excluded-address 172.17.1.65 172.17.1.66
ip dhcp excluded-address 172.17.1.2
ip dhcp excluded-address 172.17.0.2
ip dhcp excluded-address 172.17.2.38
!
ip dhcp pool ICH-HR
 network 172.17.2.32 255.255.255.240
 domain-name 
 dns-server 172.17.1.195 172.17.1.196
 default-router 172.17.2.33
!
ip dhcp pool ICH-ACC-DHCP-POOL
 network 172.17.2.16 255.255.255.240
 domain-name 
 dns-server 172.17.1.195 172.17.1.196
 default-router 172.17.2.17
!
ip dhcp pool STAFF-GUEST-MOBILE
 network 172.17.0.0 255.255.255.0
 dns-server 4.2.2.2 8.8.8.8
 domain-name 
 default-router 172.17.0.1
!
ip dhcp pool STAFF-WIFI-DHCP-POOL
 network 172.17.1.0 255.255.255.192
 dns-server 172.17.1.195 172.17.1.196
 default-router 172.17.1.1
 domain-name 
!
ip dhcp pool ICH-PRINTERS-DHCP-POOL
 network 172.17.2.64 255.255.255.248
 dns-server 172.17.1.195 172.17.1.196
 domain-name 
 default-router 172.17.2.65
!
ip dhcp pool ICH-COMMERCONTRACTING-DHCP-POOL
 network 172.17.8.0 255.255.255.224
 default-router 172.17.8.1
 domain-name 
 dns-server 172.17.1.195 172.17.1.196
!
ip dhcp pool ICC-DESIGN-DHCP-POOL
 network 172.17.8.32 255.255.255.224
 dns-server 172.17.1.195 172.17.1.196
 default-router 172.17.8.33
 domain-name 
!
ip dhcp pool ICC-PROJECTS-DHCP-POOL
 network 172.17.8.64 255.255.255.224
 dns-server 172.17.1.195 172.17.1.196
 default-router 172.17.8.65
 domain-name 
!
ip dhcp pool ICC-ADMINISTRATION-DHCP-POOL
 network 172.17.8.96 255.255.255.224
 default-router 172.17.8.97
 domain-name 
 dns-server 172.17.1.195 172.17.1.196
!
ip dhcp pool ICH-RECEPTION-DHCP-POOL
 network 172.17.2.72 255.255.255.248
 default-router 172.17.2.73
 domain-name
 dns-server 172.17.1.195 172.17.1.196
!
ip dhcp pool ICH-EXEC-DHCP-POOL
 network 172.17.1.64 255.255.255.192
 dns-server 172.17.1.195 172.17.1.196
 domain-name
 default-router 172.17.1.65
!
!
ip domain-name 
ip name-server 172.17.1.195
ip name-server 172.17.1.196
vtp mode off
!
spanning-tree mode rapid-pvst
spanning-tree extend system-id
no spanning-tree vlan 20,30,50,70,80,90,100,120,130,140,150,160,170,180
spanning-tree vlan 1,10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100,110,120,130 priority 24576
spanning-tree vlan 140-180 priority 24576
!
!
vlan 20
 name HR
!
vlan 30
 name ICH-ACCOUNTS
!
vlan 50
 name SERVERS
!
vlan 60
 name STAFF-WIFI
!
vlan 70
 name EXECUTIVES
!
vlan 80
 name PRINTERS
!
vlan 90
 name DMZ
!
vlan 100
 name OPENVPN-POOL
!
vlan 110
 name STAFF-GUEST-MOBILE
!
vlan 120
 name MANAGERS-WIFI
!
vlan 130
 name RECEPTION
!
vlan 140
 name ICH-ADMINISTRATION
!
vlan 150
 name ICC-ADMINISTRATION
!
vlan 160
 name ICC-COMMERCONTRA
!
vlan 170
 name ICC-DESIGN
!
vlan 180
 name ICC-PROJECTS
!
!
!
!
!
!
interface Port-channel1
 description ETHERCHANNEL-TO-SERVERDXBDN2
 switchport mode trunk
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/1
 switchport mode trunk
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/2
 switchport mode trunk
 speed 1000
 duplex full
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/3
 switchport mode trunk
 channel-group 1 mode active
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/4
 switchport mode trunk
 channel-group 1 mode active
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/5
 switchport mode trunk
 channel-group 1 mode active
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/6
 switchport mode trunk
 channel-group 1 mode active
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/7
 switchport access vlan 20
 switchport mode access
 switchport nonegotiate
 speed 1000
 duplex full
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/8
 switchport mode trunk
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/9
 switchport mode trunk
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/10
 switchport mode trunk
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/11
 switchport mode trunk
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/12
 switchport mode trunk
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/13
 switchport mode trunk
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/14
 switchport mode trunk
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/15
 switchport access vlan 90
 switchport mode access
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/16
 switchport access vlan 50
 switchport mode access
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/17
 switchport access vlan 60
 switchport mode access
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/18
 switchport mode trunk
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/19
 switchport access vlan 60
 switchport mode access
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/20
 switchport access vlan 50
 switchport mode access
 !
interface GigabitEthernet0/25
 switchport access vlan 80
 switchport mode access
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/26
 switchport access vlan 80
 switchport mode access
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/27
 switchport access vlan 80
 switchport mode access
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/35
 switchport access vlan 30
 switchport mode access
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/36
 switchport access vlan 30
 switchport mode access
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/37
 switchport access vlan 30
 switchport mode access
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/47
 no switchport
 ip address 172.17.2.82 255.255.255.240
!

interface Vlan1
 description NETWORKING-EQUIPMENT
 ip address 172.17.1.225 255.255.255.224
!
interface Vlan20
 description ICH-HR
 ip address 172.17.2.33 255.255.255.240
!
interface Vlan30
 ip address 172.17.2.17 255.255.255.240
!
interface Vlan50
 description SERVERS-VLAN
 ip address 172.17.1.193 255.255.255.224
!
interface Vlan60
 description STAFF-WIFI-VLAN
 ip address 172.17.1.1 255.255.255.192
!
interface Vlan70
 ip address 172.17.1.65 255.255.255.192
!
interface Vlan80
 ip address 172.17.2.65 255.255.255.248
!
interface Vlan90
 ip address 172.17.2.49 255.255.255.240
!
interface Vlan110
 ip address 172.17.0.1 255.255.255.0
!
interface Vlan130
 ip address 172.17.2.73 255.255.255.248
!
interface Vlan150
 ip address 172.17.8.97 255.255.255.224
!
interface Vlan160
 description ICC-COMMERCONTRA
 ip address 172.17.8.1 255.255.255.224
!
interface Vlan170
 ip address 172.17.8.33 255.255.255.224
!
interface Vlan180
 ip address 172.17.8.65 255.255.255.224
!
ip default-gateway 172.17.2.81
ip http server
ip http secure-server
ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 172.17.2.81 name DXBRTBHMAINRACK
ip route 172.17.1.128 255.255.255.192 172.17.2.50
ip ssh version 2
!

line con 0
 exec-timeout 20 0
 password 7 
 logging synchronous
 login local
line vty 0 4
 exec-timeout 0 0
 password 7 
 logging synchronous
 login local
 transport input ssh
line vty 5 15
 exec-timeout 0 0
 password 7 
 logging synchronous
 login local
 transport input ssh
!
end
```

**4331 Config:**

```
Current configuration : 19299 bytes
!
version 15.5
service timestamps debug datetime msec
service timestamps log datetime msec
service call-home
no platform punt-keepalive disable-kernel-core
platform hardware throughput level 100000
!
hostname DXBRTBHMAINRACK
!
boot-start-marker
boot-end-marker
!
!
vrf definition Mgmt-intf
 !
 address-family ipv4
 exit-address-family
 !
 address-family ipv6
 exit-address-family
!
enable secret 5 
!
no aaa new-model
call-home
 ! If contact email address in call-home is configured as sch-smart-licensing@cisco.com
 ! the email address configured in Cisco Smart License Portal will be used as contact email address to send SCH notifications.
 contact-email-addr sch-smart-licensing@cisco.com
 profile "CiscoTAC-1"
  active
  destination transport-method http
  no destination transport-method email
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!


ip name-server xxxxxxx

!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
subscriber templating
multilink bundle-name authenticated
!
!
!
crypto pki trustpoint SLA-TrustPoint
 enrollment terminal
 revocation-check crl
!
license udi pid ISR4331/K9 sn xxxxxxxx
license smart enable
!
spanning-tree extend system-id
!
username xxxxx secret 5 xxxxx
!
redundancy
 mode none
!
!
vlan internal allocation policy ascending
!
!
!
!
!
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/0/0
 ip address 172.17.2.81 255.255.255.240
 ip nat inside
 negotiation auto
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/0/1
 bandwidth 1000000
 ip address xxxxxxxx 255.255.255.252
 ip mtu 1492
 ip nat outside
 ip access-group vpn in
 ip tcp adjust-mss 1452
 negotiation auto
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/0/2
 no ip address
 negotiation auto
!
interface GigabitEthernet0
 vrf forwarding Mgmt-intf
 no ip address
 negotiation auto
!
interface Vlan1
 no ip address
 shutdown
!
ip default-gateway xxxxx
ip nat inside source static udp 172.17.2.52 1723 interface GigabitEthernet0/0/1 1723
ip nat inside source static tcp 172.17.2.52 1723 interface GigabitEthernet0/0/1 1723
ip nat inside source static tcp 172.17.2.52 5000 interface GigabitEthernet0/0/1 34768
ip nat inside source static udp 172.17.2.50 443 interface GigabitEthernet0/0/1 443
ip nat inside source list NAT-ALL-VLANS interface GigabitEthernet0/0/1 overload
ip forward-protocol nd
no ip http server
no ip http secure-server
ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 xxxxxx
ip route 172.17.0.0 255.255.255.0 172.17.2.82
ip route 172.17.1.0 255.255.255.192 172.17.2.82
ip route 172.17.1.64 255.255.255.192 172.17.2.82
ip route 172.17.1.128 255.255.255.192 172.17.2.82
ip route 172.17.1.192 255.255.255.224 172.17.2.82
ip route 172.17.1.224 255.255.255.224 172.17.2.82
ip route 172.17.2.0 255.255.255.240 172.17.2.82
ip route 172.17.2.16 255.255.255.240 172.17.2.82
ip route 172.17.2.32 255.255.255.240 172.17.2.82
ip route 172.17.2.48 255.255.255.240 172.17.2.82
ip route 172.17.2.64 255.255.255.248 172.17.2.82
ip route 172.17.2.72 255.255.255.248 172.17.2.82
ip route 172.17.8.0 255.255.255.224 172.17.2.82
ip route 172.17.8.32 255.255.255.224 172.17.2.82
ip route 172.17.9.0 255.255.255.0 172.17.2.82
!
!
ip access-list standard NAT-ALL-VLANS
 permit any
!
ip access-list extended vpn
 permit ip any any
ip access-list extended vpntest
 permit udp any any eq 443
 deny   ip any any
!
!
!
!
control-plane
!
!
line con 0
 logging synchronous
 login local
 stopbits 1
line aux 0
 stopbits 1
line vty 0 4
 exec-timeout 0 0
 login local
 transport input ssh
line vty 5 97
 exec-timeout 0 0
 login local
 transport input ssh
!
!
end
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include the full network device device configurations. We only have enough information to guess, but speculation and guessing are off-topic here.

Comment: Please post output of `sh platform hardware throughput level`. On these routers you have to set the throughput level. For instance in relation to your example, in config mode: `platform hardware throughput level MB 100`

Comment: @cown has been set to platform hardware throughput level 100Mb on the cisco isr 4331.This has not been done on the 2960L

Comment: You cannot set that on the 2960L switch. The command is only available on the router, but it is typically the problem, that people forget it. You need to post the configurations of the switch and router for us to help you.

Comment: Totally unrelated to the performance issue, but worth a heads up: There's no `spanning-tree portfast [trunk]` on any of the switch's ports. For end devices (non-bridges) like servers, routers, PCs and Laptops, not having `portfast [trunk]` is a nuisance. A non-portfast enabled port stays blocked for 30 seconds after line protocol comes up.  That hurts DHCP clients on the PCs and Laptops, and hypervisors like VMware can not "notifiy switches" about which VM and its given MAC address are on which port (when a link comes back up after it was down). Include 'switchport nonegotiate' with that.

Comment: @Marc 'netztier' Luethi   Thanks for that, I will give that a go

Comment: I'm pretty sure the problem resides on the router. Do you have the performance license? Please post output of `show license feature` and `show license`.

Comment: Its not the router, as i mentioned plugging a laptop directly to the ISP line as well as plugging the laptop directly into the 4331 gives the required throughput. as found on the tech specs on the cisco site for 4331 you will find that the base throughput is 100Mb https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/products/collateral/routers/4000-series-integrated-services-routers-isr/data_sheet-c78-732542.html#Product-Specifications

Comment: @sixshakybones well, searching the internet only shows the fact, that other people have had exactly the same problem. A switch just forwards traffic. There's not a chance, that it would be the congestion in this scenario. The 100 Mbit throughput is the total amount the router will handle. When you have one single host attached, then of course, it will have the full bandwidth available. But connecting the router to the switch will share the bandwidth between all hosts connected through the switch. That's why you experience different throughput per user per session.

Comment: @Cown, download speeds appear to be averaging around 50Mb today, however and still persistent as ever the upload speed does not change. This morning I cam in early, no users and disconnected everything from the switch, except for my laptop. Download speed was improved but upload speed was unable to exceed 7Mb. At this moment with 60 Users connected download speeds seem to be averaging 45-50Mb and upload speeds remain unchanged. I struggle to believe that this is the router alone.. can you please link me to these posts that you mention so that I can investigate it.

Comment: @sixshakybones just search google for `Cisco ISR 4331 throughput`. Why do you have `ip mtu 1492` and `ip tcp adjust-mss 1452`on your ISP/WAN interface? Why is your 2960L switch running `ip routing`?

Comment: @Cown, IP MTU and ADJUST-MSS appeared to be providing a more stable and consistent throughput over the past week, I have negated these commands with no noticeable differences observed today compared to the past few weeks, IP routing is enabled for the routing of VLANS on the 2960, am i incorrect in believing that this is what is required to achieve routing between the vlans ?

Comment: @sixshakybones i guess, but in my career i've never seen anyone using a potential layer 2 switch as a router. Why dont you use the router to route? I'm confused.

Comment: @Cown, in an attempt to have VLANs without the need for a router on a stick topology. The routers purpose is as a gateway for the main office. This router provides VPN connectivity between branch offices. Router on a stick to manage VLANS seems impractical these days, no ?

Something to note is that we have the exact same setup at another office and we are achieving our dedicated througput at that office, only difference is that the switch is a layer 3  3com switch... so.. I dont know..

Comment: @sixshakybones That's a design i have never heard about or seen before. By the way changing the MTU to another value will only cause fragmentation if the same MTU is not carried out on all devices. Also, are you even sure, that your ISP supports that size MTU? If not, then they will definitely do fragmentation of all your packets. The most normal used MTU on the internet is 1500 bytes. I'm afraid i cannot help you any further, but i hope someone else can. Personally i would simplify the design and use the powerful router you have to do it's purpose: route.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by changing the routed port to an access port. Throughput is perfect now. 75Mb download and 25Mb upload